# Mongoose : finding documents with a specific condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm coding a news website. I've made a special page for a particular author/reporter. This page will contain all the posts by him/her .Here's the code:

In app.js,

```
    app.get("/author/:id", function(req,res) {  //latest contains all posts
    Latest.find({author:"Richard Mann"}).sort([['_id',  -1]]).exec(function(err,allLatest) {  
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("showAuthor", { latest : allLatest});
        }
    })
})
```

This code works, and the posts by the specific author appear. But how to do this for all authors (while avoiding DRY code) ? What condition should I apply while finding the documents for a specified author?

Comment: If you want to group by `author` you can use the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the input from client side and pass it to  `find({author:req.params.id}` this will check on the bases of id which you will get from your api /author/:id and make your search for any specified author

```
app.get("/author/:id", function(req,res) {  //latest contains all posts
        Latest.find({author:req.params.id}).sort([['_id',  -1]]).exec(function(err,allLatest) {  
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("showAuthor", { latest : allLatest});
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Don't know why I didn't think of this! Anyway, any chance you would know this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015578/authorization-in-node-js ?

Comment: Surely I will have a look on it. will let you know . Would you mind accepting the answer ?

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgotten to accept the answer, did it !