# Authorization in node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, authorization

Coding a news website,I'm trying to make authorization so that only the author (who posted the article) is able to edit and delete it (these buttons appear at the bottom of the page and are visible to all the users).

But then there are certain news/websites which don't have a login/sign up option. For example : http://www.denofgeek.com/us .
Because they have no authentication, does this mean that they have no authorization?
How are they able to edit/delete the articles if the settings for the authors are the same as the rest of the users ?

Code:

```
app.get("/blog/:id/:title/edit", function(req,res) {
Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog) {
    if(err) {
        res.redirect("/blog");
    } else {
        res.render("editBlog", {blog : foundBlog});
    }
  })
})

//UPDATE BLOG
app.put("/blog/:id/:title", function(req,res) {
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog,{new: true}, function(err,updatedBlog) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect("/blog");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/blog/" + req.params.id + "/" + req.params.title);
        }
    })
})
```

How should I go about editing/deleting the articles if I don't want to use authentication?

P.S : I can, of course, remove the edit and delete buttons appearing on the page and send PUT and DELETE requests via Postman, but it's obviously a bad idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going though the website you mentioned the have one for users and one is separate for admin where author can login and make updates add new post and delete old once.

It is not possible that without any authentication you can make edits / delete for a specific user.

So you should do it like just create a separate panel for author and set a login page for that so only the authorized person can enter the page and there you can implement the functionality of deleting/updating even I would advice you to use  authorization so if anyone came to know about your apis they cant make edits until they have the token to that you can use this [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to implement authorization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can they different settings for users and admins if they don't even a login/signup button? Do you mean to say that they might another domain ( like admin.denofgeek.com ) which is only for the authors ? God... I don't even know where to begin with! I have the authentication ( via passport) set up, but I'm having trouble with the authorization part!

Comment: yes its something like that only you don't need to create another domain you can just make a url like [link](http://www.denofgeek.com/admin) where you can authenticate with userName and password and after successful check you can make author visible those sections from where they can edit/delete the post.

Comment: If possible, could you invite me to a chat room on SO, so that I can ask you whenever I feel stuck on this admin interface thing ? Commenting is a pain.

Comment: @eknoor4197 we need to do some more comments to do this if you facing any problem you can ask here only.

Comment: There might be an option to create a chat room in your footer, I don't have that since my reputation is below 100. Anyways, I'll ask you my doubts tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, I'm stuck! Would really appreciate if you take a look at it :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052194/node-js-authorization-for-specific-users

Comment: @eknoor4197 please accept the answer and upvote it if worked for you.