# Node.js Authorization for specific users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my blog website, the specific article page has 2 options at the bottom (Edit & Delete), which should only visible to the author. Code :

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
res.locals.currentUser = req.user; //stores the current logged in user
res.locals.fullUrl = fullUrl;
next();
```

})

```
//EDIT BLOG - FORM
app.get("/blog/:id/:title/edit", function(req,res) {
      //check if user is logged in
      if(req.isAuthenticated()) {  
        Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog) { //finds the specific article
        if(err) {
            res.redirect("/blog");
        } else {
            console.log(foundBlog.author); //both have same output
            console.log(req.user.username); //both have same output
            //check if the current logged in user is the author
            if( foundBlog.author == req.user.username ) { 
                res.render("editBlog", {blog : foundBlog}); //renders edit form
            } else {
                res.send( "YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO DO THAT!");
            }
        }
    })
      } else {
        res.send("YOU NEED TO BE LOGGED IN TO DO THAT!");
      }
})
```

In showBlog.ejs,

```
        <div id="main-blog-content"><%- blog.body %></div> // content of article

        <% if( currentUser && currentUser.username == blog.author ) { %> //this condition never fulfills and the edit and delete buttons never show up

        <a class="ui secondary basic button" href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>/<%= blog.title %>/edit">Edit</a>

        <form action="/blog/<%= blog._id %>/<%= blog.title %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
            <button class="ui secondary basic button">Delete</button>

        </form>
```

The problem is : `currentUser && currentUser.username == blog.author`!
This condition is never fulfilled for some reason.
Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Does the template get rendered before your API call completes?

Comment: Can you also console.log out `res.locals.currentUser` to see if it has the value you expect? It might be that the req.user value isn't populated when that middleware is run.

Comment: Umm, well it console.log res.locals.currentUser and it's coming as undefined! But that's why I used fulfilling of both conditions ( 
        `currentUser && currentUser.username == blog.author` ) .

Comment: why cant you set an authentication based process?. when an author you can set a secret key say accessToken and authorized the user on the bases of that accessToken. On your client side store that token in local storage. now if you dont have accesToken present you need not to show edit/ delete to user but if you have that you can show edit/delete and even can authorized  access from your backend by checking accessToken.

Comment: @ShumiGupta It **is** an authentication based process. I had the above problem because I was requiring a module later on. Glad that it's fixed now! :D

Comment: @eknoor4197 great.